# Timer should run even if the app is in background mode

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am using not a timer but for loop for showing timer which is 59 seconds and when it comes to 0, it will navigate to parent screen. 
Here is my code

the problem is with both Android and iOS device that when i put app in background mode it restart the time from 59 sec. what i want is if user put app in background mode e.g. when timer is 40 sec and after 10 sec again if user put app in foreground mode , timer should show 30 sec. timer should be never restarted.
The strange thing is sometimes it's working fine as expected .

in my OnAppearing method

```
 protected override void OnAppearing()
  {
        base.OnAppearing();
        var dd = (EmployeePunchScreenModel)this.Content.BindingContext;
        dd.IsbreakLoopTimer = false;
        dd.SavedDuration = true;
        Initialization = dd.ShowingTimer(59);   
   }
```

in ViewModel class -

```
 public async Task ShowingTimer(int second)
    {
        for (int _minute = 1; _minute >= 0; _minute--)
        {
            for (int _second = second; _second >= 0; _second--)
            {
                if (!SavedDuration)
                {
                    break;
                }
                if (_second < 10)
                {
                    TimerSec = Convert.ToString("0" + _second);
                }
                else
                {
                    TimerSec = Convert.ToString(_second);
                }
                if (_second == 0)
                {
                    ShouldRun = false;
                    IsbreakLoopTimer = true;
                    await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopModalAsync();
                    MessagingCenter.Send<EmployeePunchScreenModel, string>(this, Constants.Global.NOTIFY_PUNCHCALL, "FromEmpPunchViewModel");
                    return;
                }
                if (_second <= 19)
                {
                    TimerColor = "#FD3A2D";
                }
                else
                {
                    TimerColor = "#000000";
                }
                if (IsbreakLoopTimer)
                {
                    break;
                }

                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's how android works ... you should use platform-specific API for this (AlarmManager)

Comment: can you please elaborate which API or Do I need to use Dependency Service?

Comment: This is a horrible way to implement a timer. You'd be better off storing a start time and recalculating the elapsed time as part your render loop.

Comment: @ChrisPickford can you please provide code for the same?

Comment: If you store the time the alarm should go off during OnDisapearing, and set an alarm. See Plugin.LocalNotifications nuget package for cross platform alarms.

Comment: @RahulShrimali I'm not here to write code for you. You have enough information from the comments here to do the research you need.

Comment: @Neil let me try with that i got the issue the problem is occurring because sometime OnDisappear get called and sometime its not when we put app in background mode.OnDisappearing is not supposed to be called when the app goes to the background am i right?

Comment: @ChrisPickford i was only asking if you face such kind of scenario then you might have did the code . anyways thanks for your time.

Comment: https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-background-tasks/